mysql bulk rename, move a part of the string values from the beginning to the end of the string
example
I have the following string values
'[123] X'
'[123] Y'
'[123] Z'
...

I want to bulk change them to
'X [123]'
'Y [123]'
'Z [123]'
...

X, Y, Z are completely random not sequential
[123] is constant
I think the example above explains it all

and your best attempt is?

I would use the REPLACE() function.
REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)

First remove the [123] from the string. Then add it again at the end of the string:
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CONCAT(REPLACE(column_name, '[123] ', ''), ' [123]');


I would add ..WHERE column_name LIKE '[123]%' to prevent that other rows are changed.

worked well, thank you @Remco K.
and thanks Jonas Metzler for the complement, it was helpful too

MySQL regex query:
select st,
  concat(
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(st, '\\w+$', 1), ' ', 
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(st, '^\\[\\d+\\]', 1)
  ) as result
from T;

Alternative:
SELECT st,
  concat(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(st,' ',-1), ' ',
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(st,' ',1)
  ) as result
FROM T

Little bit complex:
set @r1 = '^\\[\\d+\\]';
set @r2 = '\\w+$';

select st,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(st, @r1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(st, @r2, 1), 1),
                @r2, REGEXP_SUBSTR(st, @r1, 1)
   ) as result
from T;

Sample Output: db<>fiddle

